# Another approach for calculating the sum

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\cos \beta)^{n} \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}, \beta\in(o,\pi)
$$

Answer:
$$\frac{\pi-2\arcsin\cos\beta}{2\sin\beta}=\frac{\beta}{\sin\beta}$$

I have an indirect proof， but it is more complicated. I believe there is a more elegant way to do this.

My complicated answer:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\mathrm{d} \alpha}{1+\cos \alpha \cos \beta} =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\cos \alpha \cos \beta)^{n} \mathrm{~d} \alpha \\
  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\cos \beta)^{n} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^{n} \alpha \mathrm{d} \alpha \\
  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\cos \beta)^{n} \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)} \\
$$
On the other hand:
$$\int \frac{d x}{1+\varepsilon \cos x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon^{2}}} \operatorname{arctan}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}} \operatorname{tan} \frac{x}{2}\right)+C, \varepsilon\in(-1,1)$$
In this way, I can get the answer. But it is complicate. So I need help.

Comment: Where is this question from? it's a nice one.

Comment: I met in the process of calculation, but I don't know how to directly sum the series.

Answer (score 4):

Using Legendre's duplication formula, $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+1/2)=2^{1-2z}\pi^{1/2}\Gamma(2z)$, your sum
$$\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\cos \beta)^{n} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$$
can be rewritten
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\cos \beta)^{n}\frac{2^{1-n}\pi^{1/2}\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n/2)}\frac{2}{n\Gamma(n/2)}
=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\frac{(n-1)!}{n\Gamma^2(n/2)}.
$$
where $x=-1/2\cos\beta$. Splitting into $n$ even/odd and applying the duplication formula again gives,
$$\frac{\pi}{2}+\left(2\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2n}\frac{(2n-1)!}{2n(n-1)!^2}\right)+\left(2x+\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(4x)^{2n+1}\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+1)}\frac{(n-1)!^2}{(2n-1)!^2}\right).$$
The coefficients of powers of $x$ in the left hand sum appear to be [A00170](https://oeis.org/A001700) and those of the right, $1/n$ multiples of reciprocals of Apéry numbers [A005430](https://oeis.org/A005430), so we have
$$\frac{\pi}{2}+2x+\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2n-1\choose n-1}x^{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1){2n+2\choose n+1}}(4x)^{2n+1}.$$

Mathematica has no problem evaluating these sums to obtain
$$\frac{\pi -\cos ^{-1}(2 x)}{\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}=\frac{\beta}{\sin\beta},$$
for $\beta\in(0,\pi)$. Check out [this Binomial Sums link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html) to see sums very similar to those here.

This might not be as elegant as you're looking for (evaluating the sums might not be considered elegant) but I spent some time on it so thought I'd show it anyway.

Comment: You are modest. In my opinion, it is better than my method. Moreover, it is elegant in my mind! Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, let us wait for other method to solve the sum.